# How to add a non-property rule in FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have this validator class:

```
internal class CustomerTypeValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerType>
{
    public CustomerTypeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Number).Must(BeANumber).WithState(x => CustomerTypeError.NoNumber);
    }

    private bool BeANumber(string number)
    {
        int temp;
        bool ok = int.TryParse(number, out temp);

        return ok && temp > 0;
    }
}
```

And I have the service class:

```
public class CustomerTypeService
{
   public CustomerType Save(CustomerType customerType)
    {
        ValidationResult results = Validate(customerType);
        if (results != null && !results.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException<CustomerTypeError>(results.Errors);
        }

        //Save to DB here....

        return customerType;
    }

    public bool IsNumberUnique(CustomerType customerType)
    {
        var result = customerTypeRepository.SearchFor(x => x.Number == customerType.Number).Where(x => x.Id != customerType.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        return result == null;
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate(CustomerType customerType)
    {
        CustomerTypeValidator validator = new CustomerTypeValidator();
        validator.RuleFor(x => x).Must(IsNumberUnique).WithState(x => CustomerTypeError.NumberNotUnique);
        return validator.Validate(customerType);
    }
}
```

However I get the following exception:

`Property name could not be automatically determined for expression x => x. Please specify either a custom property name by calling 'WithName'.`

Is the above not the correct way to add an extra rule?

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem?

Comment: @Vishal Yes. Added the `Id` property to `RuleFor` and the `IsNumberUnique` method.

Comment: Can you post your answer? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current version of FluentValidation, it is possible to solve the above problem by doing the following:

```
public bool IsNumberUnique(CustomerType customerType, int id)
{
    var result = customerTypeRepository.SearchFor(x => x.Number == customerType.Number).Where(x => x.Id != customerType.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    return result == null;
}

public ValidationResult Validate(CustomerType customerType)
{
    CustomerTypeValidator validator = new CustomerTypeValidator();
    validator.RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(IsNumberUnique).WithState(x => CustomerTypeError.NumberNotUnique);
    return validator.Validate(customerType);
}
```